# Gráfico de barras em uma reactable

Tags: javascript, html, r

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou tentando colocar um gráfico de barras dentro de uma `reactable`, mas estou tendo dificuldade em colocar o gráfico nos totalizadores. Segue um exemplo:

```
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)
bar_chart <- function(label, width = "100%", height = "16px", fill = "#00bfc4", background = NULL) {
  # https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/cookbook/cookbook.html
  bar <- div(style = list(background = fill, width = width, height = height))
  chart <- div(style = list(flexGrow = 1, marginLeft = "8px", background = background), bar)
  div(style = list(display = "flex", alignItems = "center"), label, chart)
}


formata_coluna <- colDef(aggregate = "sum",
                         footer = function(values) format(sum(values), big.mark = '.', decimal.mark = ','),
                         format = colFormat(separators = TRUE, digits = 0, locales = 'pt-BR')) 

totais_perc <- JS("function(column, state) {
        let total_total = 0
        let total_ocupadas = 0
        state.data.forEach(function(row) {
          total_total += row[\'Total\']
          total_ocupadas += row[\'Sold\']
        })
        return (total_ocupadas / total_total * 100).toFixed(2)
      }")

grupos_perc <- JS("function(values, rows) {
        let total_total = 0
        let total_ocupadas = 0
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
          total_total += row[\'Total\']
          total_ocupadas += row[\'Sold\']
        })
        return (total_ocupadas / total_total * 100).toFixed(2)
      }")

expand.grid(Seller = LETTERS[1:3], Product = letters[1:3]) %>% 
  mutate(Sold = rpois(9, 50),
         Total = Sold + rpois(9, 10),
         Perc = Sold/Total) %>% 
  bind_rows(data.frame(Seller = 'D',
                       Product = 'd',
                       Sold = 0, 
                       Total = 10,
                       Perc = 0)) %>% 
  reactable(groupBy = "Seller",
            columns = list(
              Seller = colDef(footer = "Total"),
              Sold = formata_coluna,
              Total = formata_coluna,
              Perc = colDef(cell = function(value) { 
                width <- paste0(value * 100, "%")
                bar_chart(sprintf('%.0f%%', round(value * 100, 0)), width = width, fill = "#fc5185", background = "#e1e1e1") 
              },footer = totais_perc,
              aggregate = grupos_perc,
              html = TRUE)),
            pagination = F)
```

O código acima adiciona corretamente o gráfico nas linhas da tabela original, além dos percentuais corretos nos subtotais e total. Tentei alterar as funções `totais_perc` e `grupos_perc` para que retornasse algo parecido com a função `bar_chart` (tags `<div>` com os mesmos parâmetros), mas em todas tentativas da erro (ele não renderiza nada dentro das células).

Tentei retornando isso - acredito que o erro esteja aqui, mas como não entendo muito de HTML, não consegui identificar aonde:

```
<div style="display:flex alignItems:center">90%<div style="flexGrow:1 marginLeft:8px background:#e1e1e1"> <div style="background:#fc5185 width:90% height:16px"></div></div></div>
```

[Neste site](https://observablehq.com/@d3/lets-make-a-bar-chart) eu achei outro exemplo de gráfico usando `<div>` e adaptei a função `grupos_perc`, mas está dando problema quando o valor é 0 (está mostrando barra parcialmente preenchida).

```
grupos_perc <- JS('function(values, rows) {
        let total_total = 0
        let total_ocupadas = 0
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
          total_total += row[\'Total\']
          total_ocupadas += row[\'Sold\']
        })
        return \'<div style="font: 16px sans-serif; text-align: right; color: white;"><div style="background: steelblue; padding: 16px; margin: 0px; width: \' + total_ocupadas / total_total * 100 + \'%;"></div></div>\'
                  
      }')
```